# Ionic Redirect with Value

Tags: ionic-framework

I have two pages: tab2 and request. When I click the button on tab2 I want to send id data to the request page. I don't want to use local storage, i tried:

**tab2.page.ts**

```
  clickFunc(){
    this.router.navigate(['/request', id]);
  }
```

**request.page.ts**

```
this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
 console.log(params['id']); //it gives undefined.
});
```

When i receive the id values, request pg gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code in the request.page.ts file as mentioned below:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router)
{

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params['id']); // This will give you the id param's value
    });
}
```

I hope it helps!